# Apostrophe or not

Tags: apostrophe

We are finishing our mission statement and our staff is split on if we use an apostrophe or not.

Wild Quail is committed to providing our members and their guests' (guests) with exceptional customer service.

is it guests', guests or guest's

Comment: I think it should be only guests.

Comment: I can't believe your staff is split on this.  This is very basic grammar most learn during primary education.  You don't want an apostrophe.  The correct word in your sentence is "guests".

Comment: According to sites policies shouldn't this question be transferred to English Language Learners?

Comment: @SoylentGreen They're probably not based in an English speaking country. Lots of companies think it nice to have an English sounding name but their staff don't get the proper training.

Comment: Downvoting because it's GR in its most basic form.

Comment: @Laure Good point.

Answer (score 3):

No need for any apostrophe. It is a simple plural, not a possessive. Were you to say "WQ is committed to catering for our members' and their guests' needs", then apostrophes would be called for. (After the *s*, as the words are plural.)

Answer (score 2):

You're using the plural of guest, right? If so, then you don't want the apostrophe. The apostrophe indicates the guests own something, and in this case they do not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no apostrophe. Nothing is being "possessed/owned" by the guests (it doesn't matter whether guest is plural or not; there is no possession, so no apostrophe is warranted).